# file_get_contents,CURL settings on a server

Tags: php

I am in process of providing an option similar to facebook share , wherein an external webpage contents ( content from the external page) can be displayed in my site. I am coding this using PHP and Ajax. but when i hosted my page on a free server site like www/0009.ws i get an error as below,

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /www/0009.ws

I would surely be moving this to a paid server later,
Is there a workaround if a paid service provider also does not allow me to use these options?
Do I have to setup my own server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [curl](http://us.php.net/curl) set of functions:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

assuming support is built in, which is a bit much. Honestly `file_get_contents` not having URL file access is something you should check before hand when choosing a provider.